# javascript addressbook in html table

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to make a JavaScript address book and wanted to show it in html table, but it doesn't work. The meaning is: if i click on add contact button, i can fill data in the prompt box. after that i see the result in the table, but instead of that..there is no table! and i can't add a new contact. How can i solve this problem?

JavaScript code:

```
function addcontact(){

    contactName = {
        firstName: prompt("firstname",''),
        lastName: prompt("lastname",''),
        address: prompt("address",''),
        phoneNumber: prompt("phonenumber",'')
    };

var contact = [contactName];

function printPerson(person){
    document.write(person.firstName+"<br />"+person.lastName+"<br />"+person.address+"<br />"+person.phoneNumber+"<br />");
}
function list(){
    var contactLength = contact.length;
    for(i=0; i < contactLength; i++){
        printPerson(contact[i])
    }
}
list();
};
```

and here my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>div insteller</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <style type="text/css">
            #adsressbook{width:300px;}
            #adsressbook td, th{ border:1px solid #000; padding:5px 10px;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action='' method=''>
            <table id="adsressbook">
                <tr>
                    <th>Contacten</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><script type="text/javascript" src="adress/adres.js"></script></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="add contact" onclick="addcontact()"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is there any error in browser console??

Comment: Wait don't close this!

Comment: @Jhawins it is a dupe.

Comment: To the people editing this: Don't change the OP's code in the question unless he verifies it is a typo / not his current code.

Comment: What do you mean with OP's code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something along the following lines:

```
var contacts = [];

function addcontact() {
    var person = {
        firstName: prompt("firstname", ""),
        lastName: prompt("lastname", ""),
        address: prompt("address", ""),
        phoneNumber: prompt("phonenumber", "")
    };
    contacts.push( person );
}

function resetView() {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";
}

function printPerson( person ) {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML +=
        person.firstName + " - " +
        person.lastName + " - " +
        person.address + " - " +
        person.phoneNumber + "<br />";
}

function listContacts() {
    resetView();
    var len = contacts.length;
    for (x = 0; x < len; x++) {
        printPerson( contacts[x] );
    }
}
```

Here's a JSFiddle of it working: http://jsfiddle.net/nttk6/42/

It would probably be better to change `printPerson()` and `resetView()` to use the DOM rather then `.innerHTML`. You can also recombine the functions into 1 function again if you prefer.

The main thing is to move the `contact` or in my example the `contacts` variable out of the `addContact` function otherwise it is reset each time the function is called. Also you don't want to be using `Document.Write()`.

And here's another example of it implemented as a class:

```
var ContactManager = {
    contacts: [],
    resetView: null,
    appendView: null,
    addContact: function(){
        var person = {
            firstName: prompt("firstname", ""),
            lastName: prompt("lastname", ""),
            address: prompt("address", ""),
            phoneNumber: prompt("phonenumber", "")
        };
        this.contacts.push( person );
        this.listContacts();
    },
    listContacts: function(){
        var len = this.contacts.length;
        this.resetView();
        for( x = 0; x < len; x++ ) {
            this.appendView( this.contacts[x] );
        }
    }
};

ContactManager.resetView = function(){
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";
};

ContactManager.appendView = function( person ){
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML +=
        person.firstName + " - " +
        person.lastName + " - " +
        person.address + " - " +
        person.phoneNumber + "<br />";
};
```

And the JSFiddle for the class version: http://jsfiddle.net/TPxRa/6/

Comment: i don't see the result in the table..in jsfiddle too

Comment: Did you press the show button on the first JSFiddle? I've posted a second example as well now which auto updates the table.

Comment: oooh sorry my mistake.. but means "null" false?

Comment: [Null](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_pointer#Null_pointer) basicly means a value is not set. So on the class style version I created two place holders for functions and set them up afterwards.

Comment: why did you write that code in the var ContactManager? i removed it and it works still good..

Comment: @FFBbodie It's a way of creating a something simular to a singleton class and initialising it at the same time as there would only ever be a single copy of the ContactManager class on a page. See this [Guide to Creating classes in javascirpt](http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/)

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are using `document.write()`. That function is overwriting the content of your document and inserting the text you specified. What you want to do is append a row to your table.

You can check out this example (which is written in jQuery; but makes it a lot easier).

Comment: that's right but i prefer make it without jquery.